# Magento2 : Manage currency format in multi-language website

Tags: magento2, price

I have website with two language French and English in which currency format is not matching in both store.If product has price **14,751.89 €** then it will show

**FR Store** : €14,751.89
**En Store** : 14 751,89 €

I want to change both by **14751.89 €** 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use This Module :- **https://github.com/mage2pro/currency-format**

**There Are so many Configuration Related to Currency.**

Comment: Extension is not good. PHP Fatal error:  Class '`Df\Config\Settings`' not found in `/app/code/Dfe/CurrencyFormat/Settings.php` on line 6

Comment: when i run setup:upgrade command

Comment: Is there option to be done on mini cart as it uses knockout.js