# currency format in mini cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, multicurrency

Want to convert number format into currency in mini cart.
Was able to convert it into PHP but it gets converted into another format due to JS

Number 1370000
convert to 
$1.370.000,00

[Magento2 : Manage currency format in multi-language website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225119/magento2-manage-currency-format-in-multi-language-website)

Answer (score 2):

First create di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Adamsmage\Priceformat\Model\Format" />
</config>
```

second create model file at `app/code/Adamsmage/Priceformat/Model/Format.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Priceformat\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;
class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format{

private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';
public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
{
    $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
    if ($currencyCode) {
        $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
    } else {
        $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
    }
    $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
    $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;
    $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
        ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);
    // changes are gone here.....
    $decimalSymbol = '.';
    $groupSymbol = ',';
    $pos = strpos($format, ';');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
    }
    $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
    $totalPrecision = 0;
    $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
    if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
        $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
    } else {
        $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
    }
    $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
    $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
    $pos = strpos($t, '#');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
    }
    if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
        $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
    } else {
        $group = strrpos($format, '.');
    }
    $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');
    $result = [
        //TODO: change interface
        'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
        'precision' => $totalPrecision,
        'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
        'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
        'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
        'groupLength' => $group,
        'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
    ];       
    return $result;
}}
```

Comment: thx but if i am not wrong it would be via php. Mini cart gets updated via Ajax call.